# Nodejs Request Promise How to display status code

Tags: node.js, express, node-request, request-promise

I am using the request library to make external api calls. https://github.com/request/request. I am using the native promise/async extention. https://github.com/request/request-promise-native.

However I am not able to check the status code, it is undefined.

```
public async session(): Promise<any> {

    const url = <removed>;

    const options = {

        uri: url,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': this.config.token
        },
        json: true,
        body: {
        }
    }

    try {
        const res = await request.post(options);

        if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
            // do something
        }
        console.log(res);
        console.log("statuscode", res.statusCode)
        return res;
    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}
```

The res.statusCode is undefined.

Comment: can you post the full code

Comment: @NuOneTAttygalle What detail are you missing, i have redacted the url but that shouldint be an issue.

Comment: Can you dump whole res object? I want to see what response are you getting from service? Is it undefined or there is any other issue.

Comment: @Vinay i get a single object, i have removed one field which incldued a session token but this is pretty much it. https://pastebin.com/EFzE6NhB

Comment: can you show me how you calling this?

Comment: Ive already solved this now, see my answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to the documentation we need to define in the options that we want to return the full response.

https://github.com/request/request-promise#get-the-full-response-instead-of-just-the-body

```
const options = {

        resolveWithFullResponse: true

}
```

Comment: I've moved away from this library and started to use axios instead.

Comment: does Axios has `resolveWithFullResponse`?

Comment: axios returns a schema that includes the status code: https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema

Answer (score 2):

I think res object might undefined. you can try request as callback

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {

  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 

});
```

or you can do like this 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

```
var options = {
    uri: 'http://the-server.com/will-return/404',
    simple: true,
    transform: function (body, response, resolveWithFullResponse) { /* ... */ }
};

rp(options)
    .catch(errors.StatusCodeError, function (reason) {
        // reason.response is the transformed response
    });
```

Comment: I need to return a promise. Thats . the whole reason for using the promise-native library. The respone is not undefined it contains a object with the correct fields. but there is just no respones codes